# MySQL: lookup multiple foreign key values before insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temporary table `tmp_c` of new info that I need to insert into the `metric` table:

```
mysql> select host, metric, value from tmp_c limit 2;
+----------+----------+--------+ 
| host     | metric   | value  |
+----------+----------+--------+
| host1    | %        | 86     |
| host2    | Kbs      | 6529   |
+----------+----------+--------+

mysql> select * from hostID limit 1;
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |  host1       |
+----|--------------+

mysql> select * from metricID limit 1;
+----+------------+
| id | metric     |     
+----+------------+
|  1 | %          | 
+-----------------+

mysql> select id, hostID, metricID, value from metric limit 1;
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| id       | hostID   | metricID  | value   |
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1        | 1        | 1         | 86      |
| 2        | 1        | 2         | 7765    |
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

How can I look up the foreign keys for hostID and metricID, and insert the data from `tmp_c` into `metric`?

I got it working using the below for another query in different tables using only one foreign key relationship: (but can't get it to work using two in this case). Maybe use a view?

```
INSERT IGNORE into host(cluster_id, name, numcpu, cpu_tot_mhz, mem_tot) 
     SELECT c.id as cluster_id, t.Entity as name, t.numcpu as numcpu,
     t.CpuTotalMhz as cpu_tot_mhz, `Total Memory` as mem_tot from tmp_c t
     INNER JOIN cluster c on c.name = t.Cluster;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two joins:

```
insert into metric(hostid, metricid, value)
    select h.id, m.id, c.value
    from tmp_c c join
         host h
         on c.host = h.name join
         metricid m
         on c.metric = m.metric;
```

This assumes that the id is auto incremented, so it doesn't need to be passed in.